# Not able to merge the tables to get the desired result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have following 3 tables

```
suppliers
id  job_title
1       S1
2       S2
3       S3
6       S6

supplier_job
id   supplier_id   job_id
1       1            1
2       2            2
3       3            1
4       6            2

job_report
Id    report  supplier_id  job_id
1       R1      1            1
2       R2      1            1
3       R3      1            1
4       R4      3            1
5       R5      3            1
6       R6      6            2
```

The below code gives me a list of suppliers that are against a particular job

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('job_id',$job_id);
$this->db->from('supplier_job');
$this->db->join('suppliers','supplier_job.supplier_id=suppliers.id','Right');
$query=$this->db->get();
$r = $query->result();
```

However, along with this list i wish to get the total number of reports submitted per supplier against that job, so according to it the result should be like

> If job_id = 1 then

```
job_id supplier_id   total_report
1           1           3
1           3           2
```

Can anyone please tell how to get the desired result

Comment: With query questions the best thing you can do is set up a http://sqlfiddle.com/
to try yourself or let others try to get the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this mysql query.

```
SELECT 
    p.job_id,
    p.supplier_id,
    Count( p.report ) AS total_report
FROM 
    job_report p 
WHERE 
    p.job_id = 1
GROUP BY 
    p.job_id,
    p.supplier_id
```

Output:

```
Job_id  supplier_id  total_report
 1         1           3
 1         3           2
```

Comment: is there a way where instead of writing all the parameters i can use *

Comment: I don't know another way. Did you try this sql? is it working?

Comment: I am getting proper result with this sql